# Why does a TypeError in commented out line stop my code from running?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I keep getting a "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__" in a line that is commented out. Why is this stopping the script from running? What am I missing here? Thankful for any suggestions!

I am using jupyter notebook with python 3.6.3 and pytorch 1.0.0.

```
      62             loss = -torch.mean(self.conv_output)
 ---> 63             # print('Iteration:', str(i), 'Loss:', "{0:.2f}".format(str(loss.data.numpy())))

 TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

Comment: It sounds like you are running code from a stale `pyc` file that *doesn't* have that line commented out.

Comment: @chepner I see, that makes sense. I copied the code into my notebook and accessed it there, that did solve the problem, thank you!